# How to preserve order while doing except function in a spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I have to apply some limits on the spark dataset and have to create a subset of a spark dataset and need to extract one row from that dataset. I implemented this logic by using, except and limit function of the dataset. The problem here is when i use except the order of the dataset has been changed. For my logic, to preserve the order is imp.

Eg. My dataset is : Dataset having 3 rows

**Chocolates
IceCreams
SoftDrinks**

I want to fetch Icecreams, when i apply limit and except i am getting my subset as

SoftDrinks
IceCreams

which will give me SoftDrinks(will convert the subset to Java list and will fetch the first element of the list)

Or is there any way to fetch the rows in a dataset by passing only the index??something like   **dataset.get(0)**

Comment: You can use orderBy clause on dataset. Did you check the API? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Comment: Please elaborate on the example with verifiable code, if possible

Answer (score 0):

In general case you cannot preserve order using `expcept` because it is an operation which requires shuffle. In some cases (small reference), you can use broadacst join or bloom filter to achieve similar effect.

However, thinking about `Datasets` in terms of ordering, unless order is explicit enforced with `orderBy`, is a huge mistake. In general `Dataset`, like relation, is unordered. So if

> For my logic, to preserve the order is imp.

you're looking at a wrong tool.

Same:

> to fetch the rows in a dataset by passing only the index??

is not possible, because `Dataset` has no concept of index.